# Jquery Date picker Not working in Master Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net

In master page

```
    <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title></title>

<link type="text/css" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
.ui-datepicker { font-size:8pt !important}
</style>


    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

In content place holder i have tried

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
           $("input[id$='TextBox1']").datepicker();
        });                 
</script>

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
<table id="tblgv" runat="server">
<td>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
</table>
</asp:Content>
```

I have tried in asp page working fine. i don't know why its not working in master page.

Comment: If datepicker is not working then is there any error on browser console ?
Also please check weather your jquery selector is having any elements in it with alert($('selector').length)

Comment: can u show the control on which u r applying datepicker..

Comment: @user3494471 please check weather the selector is selecting any element or not

Comment: are you using any updatepanel in page?

Comment: How are you getting that element to the master page?

Comment: i think u want datepicker in your master page and show in all content page. yes? so put script out of content place holder, for ex at the bottom of your master page

Comment: @Leon_SFS i want date picker by clicking text box. my text box in content place holder.Any solution share with me.

Comment: content place holder content in master page remove by content page when load it, i think u should move the textbox and script out of the content place holder

Comment: put script at the end of content page, not in place holder header

Comment: @Leon_SFS end of content means?will u please elaborate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will Work for you...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[id$='TextBox1']").datepicker();
});

</script>
```

You could also give it a class of something like `CssClass="datePicker"` and use that to grab it with jQuery:

```
$(".datePicker").datepicker();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Like, In Your Page where Datepicker is Located

Place it at bottom of Page where you Datpicker is located,
Put This [Jquery](https://code.google.com/p/simile-widgets/source/browse/exhibit/trunk/src/webapp/api/extensions/dataeditor/jquery_ui/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js?r=2176)

```
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   
<script src="DATEPICKER.JS" type="text/javascript"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
           $("input[id$='TextBox']").datepicker();
        });                 
</script>
```

Comment: add my script in <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server"> //here add it </asp:Content> and remove from ID="Content1"

Answer (score 1):

change ur content page code to this, remove datepicker style from master page

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
<style type="text/css">
    .ui-datepicker { font-size:8pt !important}
</style>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
<table id="tblgv" runat="server">
<td>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
</table>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    `$(function () {
       $("input[id$='TextBox1']").datepicker();
    });                 
</script>
</asp:Content>
```

if not working!!! please write ur html result from this content in ur browser here